# Clicking on multiple play buttons MediaPlayer starts playing multiple audios at same time

Tags: android, listview, audio, media-player

I have a listview which displays list of tracks.Each list item has play and stop icons to play and stop track.The issue that i am having is that if i click on multiple play buttons MediaPlayer plays multiple audios at same time and then if i try to stop multiple audios app crashes.how to prevent MediaPlayer  from playing multiple audios at same time?I want that if mediaplayer is playing one track and user clicks on another play button mediaplyer should stop playing previous track and play the track of the play button user clicked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create only one instance of `MediaPlayer` object, on adapter constructor, like this:

```
public class SoundCloudAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SoundCloud> soundcloudList;

    public SoundCloudAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SoundCloud> soundcloudList)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.soundcloudList = soundcloudList;
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return soundcloudList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return soundcloudList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.soundcloud_item, null);
            holder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.textview2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            holder.textview3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.download);
           // holder.btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            holder.img1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.play2);
            holder.img2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pause);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textview.setText(soundcloudList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.textview2.setText(soundcloudList.get(position).getId());
        holder.textview3.setText("Play Count : "+soundcloudList.get(position).getDownload());
        if(soundcloudList.get(position).getPlaying())
        {
            holder.img1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v)
            {
                soundcloudList.get(position).setPlaying(true);
                try
                {
            holder.img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    {
                        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
                    }

                    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/" + soundcloudList.get(position).getId() + "/stream?client_id=xyz");
                    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                        {
                            mp.start();

                        }
                    });
                    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(
                            new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
                                {
                                    soundcloudList.get(position).setPlaying(false);
                                    holder.img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    holder.img2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                }
                            });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });
        holder.img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v)
            {
                soundcloudList.get(position).setPlaying(false);


                holder.img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.img2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        mMediaPlayer.pause();


            }

        });

        return convertView;

    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView textview;
        public TextView textview2;
        public TextView textview3;
        public ImageView img1;
        public ImageView img2;
        public Button btn;
    }

}
```

Comment: okay..putting   mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); inside SoundCloudAdapter constructor doesn't play the audio when clicking on play button second time..if i played a track and then stopped it and then try to play same or another track then it will not play..if i am playing a track and clicked on play icon of another track it will stop the current track but does not play the another track..

Comment: same issue..if i played a track and then stopped it and then try to play same or another track then it will not play..if i am playing a track and clicked on play icon of another track it will stop the current track but does not play the another track..

Comment: I think that you are renewing the adapter several times...
The solution that you need is to pass the mediaPlayer object into constructor ...

Comment: should i post the main class and SoundCloud class?

Comment: Track doesn't get played every second time when i click on play icon.That means if i click on play icon for first time then track starts playing and then after clicking on stop icon if i try to play track again by clicking on play icon then it doesn't get played but icon does get changed from play icon to stop icon as expected.Then after clicking on stop icon if i again try to play track then track starts playing.Overall,track doesn't get played every second time i click on play icon

Answer (score 0):

> The issue that i am having is that if i click on multiple play buttons
>   MediaPlayer plays multiple audios at same time

Its because you create a new instance of `MediaPlayer` everytime `onClick` trigerred :

```
 mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

Create the instance **once** (in `onCreate`, for example), and just change the url in `onClick` method.

Comment: i tried tht also..if i put  mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); inside  getView() then audio doesn't pause on clicking pause button..once played it keeps playing..

Comment: check out updated question with code for SoundCloudFragment.java and SoundCloud.java

Comment: if i put mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); inside SoundCloudAdapter constructor track doesn't get played every second time when i click on play icon.That means if i click on play icon for first time then track starts playing and then after clicking on stop icon if i try to play track again by clicking on play icon then it doesn't get played but icon does get changed from play icon to stop icon as expected.Then after clicking on stop icon if i again try to play track then track starts playing.Overall,track doesn't get played every second time i click on play icon